# One api for fetching one data or one api for fetching multiple data togetter?

Tags: java, frontend

I got a problem on how design the webpage api as the image I attached.there is 8 sections(as red boxes marked) of data should being displayed in one webpage . how to design api for this page? One api for fetching one data or one api for fetching multiple data togetter between frontend and backend?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better one API for fetching multiple data together between frontend and backend. Afterwards you can manage the data as you want in the frontend. If you want I try to get you a small demo if you give me more details. What frontend and backend framework do you use?